# How can I list and delete GCP AppEngine images from the command line?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry

I'd like to delete my old unused AppEngine images from Google Cloud Platform, so that I'm not charged for storing them.

I can manually list and delete the images created for my GCP AppEngine project from this URL:
https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID

(Obviously, replace GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID with an appropriate GCP project id.)

Is there a way to list them from the command line?  e.g. via `gcloud`?

This doesn't work as I would expect:

```
$ gcloud compute images list --no-standard-images
Listed 0 items.
```

Neither does this:

```
$ gcloud container images list 
Listed 0 items.
Only listing images in gcr.io/GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID. Use --repository to list images in other repositories.
```

It's a little painful to go in and delete lots of these manually since each image under https://console.cloud.google.com/gcr/images/GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID/US/appengine is in a separate directory that I have to first click into to select the image and then click the delete button, and then go back out to  the appengine directory and start the process again for any other images.

Comment: I'm not a flex env user, but maybe try to see if [`gcloud app versions`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/versions/) `list|delete` and/or [`gcloud app services`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/app/services/) `list|delete` can do what you want as a side effect of deleting versions/services.

Comment: @DanCornilescu, thanks, those commands match what I see at https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/versions but when I delete an old version (via the website) it doesn't automatically delete the corresponding image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Listing images

Thanks to LundinCast's answer, I used us.gcr.io as the hostname and I was able to do this:

```
$ gcloud container images list --repository=us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID
NAME
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine
```

Apparently AppEngine uses a nested repository:

```
$ gcloud container images list --repository=us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine
NAME
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t162317
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181113t132223
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181113t150454
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/default.20181108t184629
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/default.20181108t205831
us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/DEF.20181113t163644
```

This didn't work as I expected though:

```
$ gcloud container images list --repository=us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425
Listed 0 items.
```

Instead, I had to do:

```
$ gcloud container images list-tags us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425 
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
c8e3797d36b2  latest  2018-11-10T12:57:58
```

## Deleting images

According to the [documentation for deleting images](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing#deleting_images), it is possible to delete ...

- An image identified by its digest
- An image identified by its tag, and it has multiple tags

### Deleting images by (implicit) tag

When I tried to delete the single version / tag, I was shown a prompt:

```
$ gcloud container images delete us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425 
WARNING: Implicit ":latest" tag specified: us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425
Digests:
- us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425@sha256:c8e3797d36b27599c91e231afd5521e6a1283319fce5a0fd978b7cdcdb1d4181
  Associated tags:
 - latest
Tags:
- us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425:latest
This operation will delete the tags and images identified by the 
digests above.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  n

ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.delete) Aborted by user.
```

This is a little problematic for writing a script or program that can delete old images automatically (although I could pipe the [yes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yes_(Unix)) command into the `gcloud container images delete IMAGE` command); luckily there is a `--quiet` argument that can be used:

```
$ gcloud container images delete us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425 --quiet
WARNING: Implicit ":latest" tag specified: us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425
Digests:
- us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425@sha256:c8e3797d36b27599c91e231afd5521e6a1283319fce5a0fd978b7cdcdb1d4181
  Associated tags:
 - latest
Tags:
- us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425:latest
Deleted [us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425:latest].
Deleted [us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t125425@sha256:c8e3797d36b27599c91e231afd5521e6a1283319fce5a0fd978b7cdcdb1d4181].
```

So, that worked.

### Deleting images by digest

Trying again on another image, with the digest method of deleting images:

```
$ gcloud container images list-tags us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726
DIGEST        TAGS    TIMESTAMP
4d860e73f85f  latest  2018-11-10T15:50:55
```

Surprise!  You can't just use the digest as listed:

```
$ gcloud container images delete us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726@4d860e73f85f
ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.delete) [us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726@4d860e73f85f] digest must be of the form "sha256:<digest>".
```

This was a little odd (there's only one tag, "latest", and it's not even shown in the error) :

```
$ gcloud container images delete us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726@sha256:4d860e73f85f
ERROR: Tags:
ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.delete) This operation will implicitly delete the tags listed above. Please manually remove with the `untag` command or re-run with --force-delete-tags to confirm.
```

OK, let's use `--force-delete-tags` :

```
$ gcloud container images delete us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726@sha256:4d860e73f85f --force-delete-tags
Digests:
- us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726@sha256:4d860e73f85fdddb485e85dc867653e3e6095a5225f4f670200c98ede10fb542
  Associated tags:
 - latest
This operation will delete the tags and images identified by the digests above.

Do you want to continue (Y/n)?  n

ERROR: (gcloud.container.images.delete) Aborted by user.
```

As before, let's use `--quiet` to prevent showing the prompt:

```
$ gcloud container images delete us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726@sha256:4d860e73f85f --force-delete-tags --quiet
Digests:
- us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726@sha256:4d860e73f85fdddb485e85dc867653e3e6095a5225f4f670200c98ede10fb542
  Associated tags:
 - latest
Deleted [us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726:latest].
Deleted [us.gcr.io/GCP_PROJECT_ID/appengine/ABC.20181110t154726@sha256:4d860e73f85fdddb485e85dc867653e3e6095a5225f4f670200c98ede10fb542].
```

So, deleting by digest requires a more verbose command line.

Answer (score 2):

The link to the Developer Console you provided refers to the [Container Registry](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/overview), where your container images are stored, including those created during App Engine Flexible deployments.

You can list these images by location using the following gcloud command:

```
gcloud container images list --repository=[HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]
```

where [HOSTNAME] is one of four options: `gcr.io`, `us.gcr.io`, `eu.gcr.io`, or `asia.gcr.io`.

You can then delete images using the following command:

```
gcloud container images delete [HOSTNAME]/[PROJECT-ID]/[IMAGE]@[IMAGE_DIGEST]
```

You'll find detailed information about it in the online [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/managing).

Comment: Thanks, I missed that there were other options for the hostname.  In my case, I needed to use us.gcr.io.  There is a little more that I had to do; I'll put that in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, is by using xargs.

`gcloud container images list --repository=us.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID_HERE/appengine | xargs -I {} sh -c 'gcloud container images delete {} --quiet'`

Answer (score 0):

When running `gcloud container images list --repository=us.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID_HERE/appengine` the results are now presented in key value pairs such as

```
NAME: us.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID_HERE/appengine/default.20230428t124900
```

In order to use with the above xargs command then the value can be extracted as follows by using the format option `--format="value(name)"`

So the full command becomes
`gcloud container images list --repository=us.gcr.io/PROJECT_ID_HERE/appengine --format="value(name)" | xargs -I {} sh -c 'gcloud container images delete {} --quiet'`